# Cassandra 2.0.3 client-to-server [TSocket reads 0 bytes] error

Tags: encryption, cassandra, cqlsh

I want to enable authorization, authentication, Client/server encryption and internode encryption in Cassandra 2.0.3.. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be happening as all security configurations are working fine but when i enable "Client/server encryption" and connect to cqlsh i get error "Connection Error: TSocket read 0 bytes"..

Any one please help how is this possible? if not, then why? how is this Client/Server encryption works practically on local host?

Answer (score 4):

You have to properly setup your CQLSH to use SSL as well.

http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/security/secureCqlshSSL_t.html

If you already set up encryption on the server, then you already have a cert file, which you need to use in your `cqlshrc`:

```
[connection]
hostname = 127.0.0.1
port = 9160
factory = cqlshlib.ssl.ssl_transport_factory

[ssl]
certfile = ~/keys/cassandra.cert
```